# Apply a controltemplate on a Custom XamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, infragistics, controltemplate, wpf-style

I'm trying to make a ControlTemplate to my CustomXamDataGrid class which inherits from infragistics XamDataGrid. I want to show something like a statusbar which indicates how many records are there or selected on the bottom of the XamDataGrid.

I tried some like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomXamDataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource XamGridBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource XamGridBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomXamDataGrid}">
                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Width="22" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyleDoubleArrows}" />
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" Height="16" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />
                            </Grid>

                            <Border Height="25" 
                                        Visibility="Visible" 
                                        Grid.Row="1" 
                                        Margin="0,-1,0,0" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                       
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                        BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Label Content="Total Records: XXX (TODO: Template Binding)" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    <Label Content="Visible Records: XXX (TODO: Template Binding)" Margin="15,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    <Label Content="Selected Records: XXX (TODO: Template Binding)" Margin="15,0,30,0" Foreground="Black"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

It only shows the statusbar properly. The XamDataGrid itself with his calumns and rows are completely empty.

Comment: You have to rebuild/extend the original `ControlTemplate` and then add your modifications. Otherwise you just override the initial layout and behavior. Go to the XAML designer (graphical view) and select the original `XamDataGrid` (you may have to add it to the view _for this purpose only_). Then right-click the control and select _"Edit Template/Edit a Copy..."_ from the context menu. A dialog will open. Now, specify the resource name and the location where to save it. Click _"Ok"_ and navigate to the extracted original template of `XamDataGrid` and add your modifications.

Comment: Alternatively wrap the `CustomXamDataGrid` and the status bar into a common `StackPanel`.